# How do I set background color of color picker from API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the background color values for two color pickers from an API call.

I know something is clearly broken with how I am going about this, but I cannot wrap my head around how to properly set the background color so that it is shown in the color picker.

**Code for my Main Component:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromApi(props.id).then((rsp) => {
    setFields({
      colorOne: rsp.info?.colorOne,
      colorTwo: rsp.info?.colorTwo,
    });
  });
});

const [fields, setFields] = useState({
  colorOne: "",
  colorTwo: "",
});

// I want colorOne to be pre-populated here
<MyColorPicker
  setSelectedColor={setSelectedBackground}
  background={setSelectedBackground}
/>

// I want colorTwo to be pre-populated here
<MyColorPicker
  setSelectedColor={setSelectedTitleColor}
  background={setSelectedTitleColor}
/>
```

**Code for MyColorPicker:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BlockPicker } from "react-color";

class MyBlockPicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: this.props.background,
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
    this.props.setSelectedColor(color.hex);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlockPicker
        color={this.state.background}
        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
        triangle="hide"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyBlockPicker;
```

Any ideas on how to move forward? Thanks!

Comment: Check if `getDataFromApi` returns any data. Also should place state in `constructor` in `MyBlockPicker` read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: You are passing `setSelectedTitleColor` instead of passing hex value.

Comment: What is the `props.id` that you use to retrieve data from api? If `Main` component is React class then you cannot use `useState` and `useEffect`. They are used only in functional components.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to pass to `MyBlockPicker` a background color that you get from api and set it as `BlockPicker` color. When `BlockPicker` selects a new color then fire the event `onChangeComplete` to pass the new selected color to `Main component` using the `setSelectedColor()`.

So I have added two methods `changeSelectedColorOne() and changeSelectedColorTwo()` that will bring the new selected colors and change the `colorOne/Two`. Try the code below and let me know.

Main component

```
//if you use react class then you cannot use `useState` and `useEffect`
constructor(props:any){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   colorOne:"",
   colorTwo:""
  }
}

componentDidMount = () =>{
    getDataFromApi(props.id).then((rsp) => { 
         this.setState({colorOne: rsp.info?.colorOne, colorTwo: rsp.info?.colorTwo});
    });
}

render = () => {
    return (
    <>
        // I want colorOne to be pre-populated here
        <MyColorPicker
          setSelectedColor={this.changeSelectedColorOne}
          background={colorOne}
        />

        // I want colorTwo to be pre-populated here
        <MyColorPicker
          setSelectedColor={this.changeSelectedColorTwo}
          background={colorTwo}
        />
    </>
    );
}
```

MyBlockPicker component

```
import React from "react";
import { BlockPicker } from "react-color";

class MyBlockPicker extends React.Component<{setSelectedColor:any},{}> {
  
  constructor(props:any){}      

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.props.setSelectedColor(color.hex);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BlockPicker
        color={this.props.background}
        onChangeComplete={this.handleChangeComplete}
        triangle="hide"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyBlockPicker;
```